# MySqli Select is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I couldn't figure out why it has some problem like this. The error displayed **mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result**.
My code is like this. I don't know which one is wrong.

Have a look at my con.php.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

and this is my page.php

```
<?php
 include 'con.php';

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'username') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "  SELECT thread_id, thread_name, thread_date

        FROM forum_thread
        ORDER BY thread_date";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $thread_id = $row ['thread_id'];
            $thread_name = $row['thread_name'];
            $thread_date = $row['thread_date'];

echo "$thread_id, $thread_name, $thread_date";
```

Any ideas? Appreciate any answers from you. Cheers!

Comment: Make sure your query didn't fail. You don't check for errors.

Comment: my query is totally fine. I've tried `echo $query` and test it on sql database, and it's really working there. @JohnConde

Comment: Shot in the dark. Your column names are in fact those shown (no spaces, or hyphens), and you have data in each? Plus, your DB connection is in fact `mysqli` and not `mysql`? Can you also try `foreach($result as $row)` instead of a `while`? And maybe a `SELECT *`

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for not being clear. Please have a look at my question again, I've updated it. And I've tried both and it still the same having problem. @Fred-ii-

Comment: From what I saw in your comment below, where does `abc` come into the picture? That's an alias. Did you try `SELECT ... FROM abc.forum_thread` ?

Comment: *abc* is supposed to be a database name. I'm really sorry for not being clear again. *abc* is just an example.

Comment: See my answer below, I think it's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

Change `$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);`

to `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);` since `$conn` is your DB connection, not `$link`

as per what you posted above

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

and remove:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'username') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

since you're already loading your DB con with `include 'con.php';`

Or this way:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));

$query = "  SELECT thread_id, thread_name, thread_date

        FROM forum_thread
        ORDER BY thread_date";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $thread_id = $row ['thread_id'];
            $thread_name = $row['thread_name'];
            $thread_date = $row['thread_date'];

echo "$thread_id, $thread_name, $thread_date";
```

Comment: Don't forget db name :) `$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');`

Comment: Yes you're right John. Good catch, thanks will fix it now. @JohnMcMahon `+1` on your comment btw.

Comment: Nah, it works now. really magic. Thanks to @JohnMcMahon and fred Really glad to know you!

Comment: That's great news and you're welcome. @user3246061 Glad to have another `Happing Ending`

Comment: @Fred-ii- anyway, can you check my other question? It is all about passing variables. I really can't figure it out, and even don't know how to start.. Can you have a check on that?

Comment: @user3246061 You should mark Fred's as the answer since it is the most complete

Comment: Yes yes, I thought I have accepted the answer but i was not. That answer is accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I left a comment under your other question just now. @user3246061

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the query did fail for some reason. Instead of just using `$result` test to see if it's valid and if not output the error to the screen or a log file:

```
if ($result) { 
  // continue processing $result 
}
else {
  echo mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Edit:
The 4th parameter in the mysqli_connect should be the name of the database, "abc" or whatever.

Comment: Hey, thank you for that. finally i can have a look at the real error message. But, I couldn't figure it out what is this mean. like **Table 'abc.forum_thread' doesn't exist**.. what does it mean? The table is actually stay there, and it is really exist there.

Comment: This means the table "forum_thread" doesn't exist in the database "abc". Are you connecting to the right database on the right host?

Comment: yes, it is correct. Anyway have a look at my question. I've updated it. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli-   >connect_error;
}
```

Here when you try to get connection object itself you can identify the problem if something goes wrong.

Comment: somehow i find it's good too. btw, i've found the solution, the answer is above. thanks and appreaciate it!